# Updates listed but not installed

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, gnome, 64-bit, multiarch

After upgrading to 12.04 Gnome Classic amd64, several updates are listed in update manager, but do not install.  In my x86 upgrade this is not happening.  The amd64 upgrade is a disaster with many things not working, but the x86 works fine.

The items are: ia32-libs-multiarch:i386; banshee-extension-soundmenu; banshee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed the problem for me:

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch

Thanks to  [Steve Langasek](https://launchpad.net/~vorlon) see his [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/1000541)

Answer (score 1):

When applications do not update it signifies that their dependencies are broken or not installed.
I do not know about `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386` .
and i think `banshee-extension-soundmenu; banshee` do not install (assuming you are installing them from a ppa) bcoz they might be having broken dependencies

Comment: This is what i have usually experienced in 10.10

Comment: I went to synaptic, apparently the multiarch lib was to repalce it's old style not multiarch, which had not been done.  when I deleted the old lib the update was successful. I had to delete google-earth and picasa but I will re-install them if I need them.  I don't use banshee so it went to read-only memory.

Comment: Oops ⋯ banshee went to write-only-memory.