# installing updates running for rever

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. The Software Updater notified me to install some updates. When I tried to do so, they are getting downloaded but during installation they get halted mid-way. Attaching a snap-shot of the same.[image: Updates failed to install]

Tried searching for similar questions like [Can't install updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553014/cant-install-updates)
and [Updates listed but not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138411/updates-listed-but-not-installed)
but didn't help much. Possibly it is giving some Perl error message which I am not able to understand properly.

Highly appreciate any help.

Comment: export LC_ALL=""                 Try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export LC_ALL=""`

Try that one, If that didn't solve that problem, you better search by this term:

> Cannot set LC_Type to default

same for others....